# FOSFacebookBundle Redirection Issue

Tags: facebook, symfony, fosuserbundle, fosfacebookbundle

I have some troubles using FOSFacebookBundle with FOSUserBundle for make a subscribtion by Facebook on my website...

There is my code:

**base.html.twig**:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<!-- TEMPLATE STUFF -->

function goLogIn(){
    alert('enter goLogin function');
    window.location = "{{ path('_security_check') }}";
}

function onFbInit() {
    alert('enter onFbInit');
    if (typeof(FB) != 'undefined' && FB != null ) {
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
            alert('Status Changed');
            if (response.session || response.authResponse) {
                setTimeout(goLogIn, 500);
            } else {
                window.location = "{{ path('_security_logout') }}";
            }
        });
    }
}
{{ facebook_initialize({'xfbml': true, 'fbAsyncInit': 'onFbInit();'}) }}
```

**config.yml**

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Modnar\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User

fos_facebook:
    file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/facebook/src/base_facebook.php
    alias:  facebook
    app_id: APP_ID                    // I put my own APP_ID here
    secret: APP_SECRET                // I put my own APP_SECRET here
    cookie: true
    permissions: [email, user_birthday, user_location]

services:
    my.facebook.user:
        class: Modnar\Bundle\UserBundle\Security\User\Provider\FacebookProvider
        arguments:
            facebook: "@fos_facebook.api"
            userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
            validator: "@validator"
            container: "@service_container"
```

**security.yml**

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    factories:
          - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/bundles/FOS/FacebookBundle/Resources/config/security_factories.xml"

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager
        my_fos_facebook_provider:
            id: my.facebook.user

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            fos_facebook:
                app_url: "http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME/" // I put my own APP_NAME here
                server_url: "http://APP_URL/"                 // I put my own APP_URL here
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_fb_check
                default_target_path: /
                provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
            logout:
                handlers: ["fos_facebook.logout_handler"]
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

**routing.yml**

```
_security_check:
    pattern:  /login_fb_check
_security_logout:
    pattern:  /logout
```

At this point, the Facebook icon is on my /login page, and I can connect to Facebook, but I'm not redirect anywhere. I put some alert on the js for get a trace, and there is just one alert displayed : "enter onFbInit". Maybe I missed a step somewhere, but I don't find it.

Thanks !

Comment: what does your FB var containt in your onFbInit function?

Comment: FB containt a lot of things. I checked what FB['Event'] containt, that's what I get:
subscribers: undefined
subscribe: undefined
unsubscribe: undefined
monitor: undefined
clear: undefined
fire: undefined
listen: undefined
unlisten: undefined

I print the FB['Event'] content after the FB.Event.subscribe call on base.html.twig.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by placing the javascript code of facebook directly after opening the the  tag.

Look what the documentation says:

> Note that we need to include this code before the initialization of
>   the Facebook Javascript SDK Initialization in order to have the
>   onFbInit() event listener correctly triggered (in this case between
>   the beginning of the 'body' tag and the templating helper provided by
>   this bundle)
>
> We wait 500ms before redirecting to let the browser deal with the
>   Facebook cookie. You can avoid this step, but you might get this error
>   message: "The Facebook user could not be retrieved from the session."